# Ver somente modificações no Diff

Tags: visual-studio

Gostaria de saber se tem como ver somente as linhas adicionadas e/ou removidas no visual studio, não no git, no compare do visual studio.

[image: Print]

Gostaria de ver somente o que foi removido/adicionado, o código que não foi alterado é dispensável (em **amarelo**), assim, daria para fazer uma lista das coisas que foram alteradas muito mais rápido.

Apesar de pequenos commits ser o ideal a se fazer, são muitas alterações de somente um assunto, então não faz sentido eu commitar várias vezes, iria ficar inviável.

Comment: Daniel R, eu achei um tutorial, veja se te ajuda: 22 MAR, 2019 [Use Git com a interface gráfica do Visual Studio Code e aumente sua produtividade](https://imasters.com.br/desenvolvimento/use-git-com-interface-grafica-visual-studio-code-e-aumente-sua-produtividade)

Comment: Acho que você já respondeu sua propria pergunta haha. Se você abrir seu projeto que esteja sendo versionado pelo git no vscode, no painel da esquerda aparecerá um botão com o icone popular de bifurcação do git, geralmente abaixo da lupa. Lá você consegue fazer todas as operações mais comuns como add, commit, diff... de modo bem simples.

Comment: o problema é que o projeto tá no tfs, não no git. A gente prefere git e tá usando em projetos mais novos, mas não nesse.

Comment: Acho que seria melhor adicionar essa informação e reformular sua pergunta, de qualquer forma uma busca rápida no google já me deu essa dica aqui: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48056972/how-to-connect-tfs-in-visual-studio-code

Comment: Não tem que reformular, pois esse não é meu problema, eu não mencionei studio code, eu quero visual studio, ver no DIFF do Visual Studio, vou colocar uma print.